# Keep name of Local Authority when converting KML to GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson, kml, topojson

I am trying to convert [this KML](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/c4a62d87de9f4b6087cf5f1515d5a0c1_0) to GeoJSON.

All I want to do is draw the map with D3 and as I hover over each local authority, have the name in a popup.

I tried [this online tool](http://2geojson.com/) and it seems to work, however I am loosing the name of places. Also when I later convert my GeoJSON to TopoJSON using [this tool](https://github.com/topojson/topojson), it isn't a reduction in size of the 80% I was expecting.

Comment: You appear to have two questions here, you should edit to provide just one. On the matter of converting the admin data to geojson, did you also try the provided shapefile, do you get the same error?